# in org-mode, how to create checkbox items in org-capture?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is it possible to create an `org-capture` template that inserts text in a capture file, under a specified heading (same heading every time) but does not create new headlines beyond that? i.e. instead of putting it under `* %U`, to put the captured text under `\n- [ ]` instead? I tried to do this but I'm getting errors.

Here is my attempt:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  (quote
   (
("l" "Later" entry (file+headline "scratch.org" "later")
 "\n\n\n- [ ] %?\n\n" :prepend t :kill-buffer t)
   )))
```

Here's what the org file looks like now:

```
* Notes  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  
* Later
* Tasks
```

Here's what it should look like after:

```
* Notes  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  
* Later
- [ ] Second capture would go here. 
- [ ] First captured text would go here. 
* Tasks
```

Comment: Can you please post a before and [proposed] after example of an org-file so that we have a clearer picture of what you are seeking -- I initially thought I understood, but now I'm not so sure any more ???

Comment: It looks like you may be interested in `file+olp` instead of `file+headline`.  It's been a while since I looked at that option, but I think it goes something like this  `(file+olp org-file level-one level-two)` -- these are essentially list bullet points underneath a heading or underneath a subheading -- it doesn't need more than one level, but is capable of it if you so desire.  And, it is not `entry`, but instead it uses `item` or a `checkitem`.

Comment: olp is for non-unique headings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In org-capture templates, `entry` creates a new heading. For checkbox items, use `checkitem` instead.

```
(setq org-capture-templates
(quote
(
("l" "Later" checkitem (file+headline "scratch.org" "later") " [ ] %?\n\n" :prepend t :kill-buffer t)
 )))
```